# Ionic: Opening html content in Inapp Browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, ngcordova

I'm trying to integrate payment gateway in an Ionic mobile app. I get the HTML code from the server which contains a form with all the post parameters and submit  on page load to call the payment gateway.

1. How can I open the in-app browser with the HTML content?
2. After the transaction, the payment gateway will call the server URL & process the response. How can I now communicate back to Ionic app to close In-app browser & show the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `exceuteScript` Api of the Cordova In-App-Browser plugin. You should be able to

1. Add the required HTML to an empty document
2. Poll the document location for completion of the payment flow

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserexecutescript

Comment: For Polling and passing back the data,  I used local storage strategy as show in the blog: https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/sharing-data-between-hybrid-app-and-inapp-browser/?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code? How to handle the response HTML from web service.